# Dropdown selectedindex not triger when used jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, drop-down-menu

I have used jquery to give effect for my dropdown but after inserting jquery i cant get the selectedindexed changed function working. But when i remove the jquery, then all seems to be working fine.

Another thing, after applying jquery in the dropdown, all the items in the dropdown are shown as list item 'li' instead of options.

I have tried using javascript function as well but same happens whenever I use jquery in the drop down.

Code goes as:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownProducts" Width="150px" CssClass="RegistryDrop" 
     runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnDataBinding="dropprodsbinding"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownProducts_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     DataTextField="Name" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
     DataValueField="id">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

code behind code goes here:

```
function getSelectOptions(parentid) {
   var select_options = new Array();
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    $select.children('option').each(function () {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.setAttribute('id', parentid + '_' + $(this).val());
        li.innerHTML = $(this).html();
        if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
            $input.val($(this).html());
            $(li).addClass(opt.currentClass);
        }
        ul.appendChild(li);
        $(li)
        .mouseover(function (event) {
            hasfocus = 1;
            if (opt.debug) console.log('over on : ' + this.id);
            jQuery(event.target, $container).addClass(opt.hoverClass);
        })
        .mouseout(function (event) {
            hasfocus = -1;
            if (opt.debug) console.log('out on : ' + this.id);
            jQuery(event.target, $container).removeClass(opt.hoverClass);
        })
        .click(function (event) {
            var fl = $('li.' + opt.hoverClass, $container).get(0);
            if (opt.debug) console.log('click on :' + this.id);
            $('li.' + opt.currentClass).removeClass(opt.currentClass);
            $(this).addClass(opt.currentClass);
            setCurrent();
            hideMe();
        });
    });
    return ul;
}
```

hoping to get some solution. thank you

Comment: please post your html code

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownProducts" Width="150px" CssClass="RegistryDrop" runat="server" 
                                    AutoPostBack="True" OnDataBinding="dropprodsbinding" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownProducts_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                    DataTextField="Name" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataValueField="id"></asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Just a note: javascript isn't actually code-behind. It is executed client-side. The code-behind is the C#/VB code that executes on the server.

Comment: there is code-behind where i have written the code for the DropDownProducts_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: I don't see any code-behind in your post. That doesn't really effect the answer to this question though - see below.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript/jquery code is converting the dropdown into an unordered list in the client's browser. After that conversion happens, any hooks that the ASP.net control had into the dropdown no longer exist, as the dropdown has been replaced with the `ul` structure.

Ultimately, all of the postback actions happen as a result of javascript code that ASP.Net imbeds into the `<select` html element. So when you replace that element, none of those actions will be called.

In theory, you should be able to identify what those attachments are using client-side analysis (Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug) to see what functions/events are attached to the `<select` in the non-jquery version of your page. Once you identify those events, you can store them as functions in javascript and attach them to events on the `<ul` structure that the jquery is replacing the `<select` with.

You'll have to do some analysis on your end to see for sure what is going on, but it could be as simple as something like (where `mySelect` and `myUL` are identifiers tied to your actual `select` and `ul` elements):

```
var functionToExec = $('#mySelect').click;
$('#myUL').children.each.click = functionToExec;
```